# Set Function name as String - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Hey I'm trying to create a String Const with the value of the function wrapping it

```
Const url = 'mainapiurl.com/api/'
    
export function GetPointsStoreBenefits() {
       const urlExtention = // I want to name it automatically like the function (GetPointsStoreBenefits)// 
FullUrl = url + urlExtention
```

I need to make a lot of calls so I was wondering is it the best practice? any suggestions?
the concept supposed to be dynamic code like this

```
const urlExtention = thisfunction.name
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to make a higher order function that you can derive your other functions from:

```js
const url = 'mainapiurl.com/api/'
    
function makeFunction(urlExtention) {
  return function() {
    const fullURL = url + urlExtention;
    
    /* do something */
    
    console.log("full URL is:", fullURL);
  }
}

/* export */ const GetPointsStoreBenefits = makeFunction("GetPointsStoreBenefits");


/* import GetPointsStoreBenefits ... */

GetPointsStoreBenefits();
```

Answer (score 0):

Function object have a `name` property, which contains the function name.
So in your case you can do something like:

```js
export function GetPointsStoreBenefits() { }
const urlExtention = GetPointsStoreBenefits.name;
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Comment: That's the Direction, But I'm looking for something less hard coded
for example - const urlExtention = thisfunction.name; 
not sure if it's possible